# How do I change the corners of a groupBox to sharp instead of round C# .NET WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, groupbox

I just started working with GroupBoxes and I was just wondering why I cant make my corners sharp, as if it was a rectangle.
I've seen a few online and thier corners arent round. Why is that?

```
 <GroupBox x:Name="howTOGroupBox" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" Header="How To" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="79" Width="221" BorderThickness="1"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you can style Your GroupBox ControlTemplate and round to 0 all of the corners:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Row="0"
                          BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White"
                          CornerRadius="0,0,0,0">
                            <ContentPresenter 
                          ContentSource="Header"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="White"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="0,0,0,0">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Im really new to XAML, how would I use that in my code? Would I just use it in the XAML editor?

Comment: Just put it in your resources, i will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the recommendation [Answer before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40061809/19304365) and modified it a little bit:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5px" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!-- Header -->
                                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                </Label>
                                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            </Grid>
                            
                            <!-- Content -->
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" Padding="10,10,10,10" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31977631)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late to the party on this one but... here's a fairly robust, if not rather more complicated than it should be, like a lot of things in WPF, answer.

Firstly, I'm not sure why there isn't a just a `CornerRadius` property on the `GroupBox` control itself. It feels like that could have been implemented quite easily.

Secondly, the reason you can't just create a `Style` that targets the `CornerRadius` of `Border` controls in the `GroupBox` is, when you look at how the framework composes a `GroupBox` from other controls, the `CornerRadius` properties of the `Border` controls it uses are hard set to the value `2`. i.e. they can't be overridden by a `Style` element.

To See how the WPF team originally created the `GroupBox` control, and to use this as a base for a square-corned `GroupBox`, right-click on one in the designer and select `Edit Template` then `Edit a Copy...`. This will then create a `Style` which targets `GroupBox` and overrides its default `Template` with a copy of exactly how the `GroupBox` control is normally composed. It will create something like the below. The simplest thing to do next is to go through and change all the `CornerRadius` elements to `0` and then reference the style as such: `<GroupBox Header="Blah" Style="{StaticResource SquareCornerGroupBox}" />`

```
<BorderGapMaskConverter x:Key="BorderGapMaskConverter"/>
<Style x:Key="SquareCornerGroupBox" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Border.OpacityMask>
                            <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="7" Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Border.OpacityMask>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```